# How to get an attribute knowing the classname in javaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get the Id or another attribute of elements, which classname I know.

```js
var removeBtns = document.getElementsByClassName("fa fa-times-circle floatright fa-fw js-modal-large notfirst");
for (i = 0; i < removeBtns.length; i++) {
  alert(removeBtns[i].id);
}
```

```html
<i id="removeBtn1" tasknr="1" class="fa fa-times-circle floatright fa-fw js-modal-large notfirst" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

I expected that the alert that says "tasknr1". Instead it said "null". Another option would be to give the tasknr, but the same problem appears.

Comment: using `removeBtns[i].getAttribute('id')` should work

Comment: @Roy You are wrong it will work with `.id`

Comment: The code you provided works. The problem must lie elsewhere.

Comment: Wait what you want `tasknr1` ! It seem meaningless to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `.getAttribute("tasknr")` for class name or id it will be work's

```js
var removeBtns = document.getElementsByClassName("fa fa-times-circle floatright fa-fw js-modal-large notfirst");

for (i = 0; i < removeBtns.length; i++) {
  //alert(removeBtns[i].id);
  alert(removeBtns[i].getAttribute("tasknr"));
}
```

```html
<i id="removeBtn1" tasknr="1" class="fa fa-times-circle floatright fa-fw js-modal-large notfirst" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```